# Problems about check a integer is zero or negative with only operator in C?

Tags: c, int, bit

```
     /*
     * isPower2 - returns 1 if x is a power of 2, and 0 otherwise
     *   Examples: isPower2(5) = 0, isPower2(8) = 1, isPower2(0) = 0
     *   Note that no negative number is a power of 2.
     *   Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>
     *   Max ops: 20
     *   Rating: 4
     */
    int isPower2(int x) {
      /*
   * Variable a checks if x is power of 2, x and x - 1 won't have a 1
   * in the same place if it's power of 2. Variable b checks if x is
   * negative or zero. Use & to combine !a and b to complete the function.
   */
        int a = x &(x+(~1+1));
        int b = ((x+(~1+1))>> 31)+1;
        return (!a)&b;

    }
```

Hello every one, I am self-learning a course called CSE351 form Washton University and am finishing the lab1 about data manipulation in C. As you 
can see about this question, I need to use the variable b to tell whether or not
the int x is zero.

And then I think that for zero or negative, if you minus one and then right shift 31 bits, adding one, you will get zero if the int is 0, and 1 if it is positive.

But however, my code didn't work,  but I found a line of code works.

```
  int b = ((!(x >> 31)) & (~(!x)));
```

I am really confused why my code don't work, can somebody tell me why?

Edit: Sorry, I didn't mention the environment of  this lab is based on int with 32 bits and 2's complement for negative.

Comment: Instead of combining multiple operations into a few set of statements, use lots of temporary variables to store each intermediate result. Then it's much easier to [debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and see exactly which operation (or operation**s**) is wrong.

Comment: Note that `x >> 31` is implementation defined if `x` is negative (or undefined if `int` has fewer than 32 bits), therefore the code you found is not strictly conforming.

Comment: What is `+(~1+1)` supposed to avaluate to? If you want to get `-1`, you could simply use `+(~0)` or maybe `+(-1)`.

Comment: Counter question: Can you tell us why you wrote your code the way you did?

Comment: Because this question is restricted to only use + not -, my thought was    Variable a checks if x is power of 2, x and x - 1 won't have a 1
   in the same place if it's power of 2. Variable b checks if x is
   negative or zero. Use & to combine !a and b to complete the function.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the list of allowed operators to use.  What about `int result = x <= 0;` ???  I assume that I cannot use `<=`, but I don't see the list of valid operators there.

Answer (score 0):

Several things to note (in your code):

- first, `(~1 + 1)` is the same as `~0`, and the same as `-1` (in two's complement).  Simpler, right?
- `x + (~0)`  is the same as `x - 1`.  Simpler, right?
- `x & (x - 1)` is `1` all the bits that **don't** change **and are 1**, when `x` is decremented.  I think what you pretend here is to write `x ^ (x - 1)` that is, the set of bits that carry to the next on a decrement.  This is the bits that change in a decrement.  It happens that all bits change iff the number is a power of two.   In case you want the bits that don't change, instead of using `^`, just use `&` (bits that *are `1` and don't change on a decrement* which must be the empty set in case of a power of two ---we have to complement the result, as this boolean gives the opposite)  This expression could be the result to get a power of two, if you consider the special case of `0` that is returned as a power of two.  As with negatives, and 0, the logarithm does not exist, so we can simply say `if (x <= 0) return 0; else return !(x & (x - 1));`  (THIS CAN BE THE REQUESTED SOLUTION) or more compact `return x <= 0 ? 0 : !(x&(x-1));`.
- `~a` as a consequence is _all the bits that **do change OR are 0** when `x` is decremented.  I'm lost completely here on what you pretend. I think you want to get if `x <= 0` but that's so easy to write in C, instead of the complications you show.

So, your intentions (I guess) is to use the number of 1 bits that don't change on a decrement, because *all bits do change for powers of two.*  Then, a possible implementation should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*
 * isPower2 - returns 1 if x is a power of 2, and 0 otherwise
 *   Examples: isPower2(5) = 0, isPower2(8) = 1, isPower2(0) = 0
 *   Note that no negative number is a power of 2.  (and zero also, there's no logarithm of zero)
 *   Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>
 *   Max ops: 20
 *   Rating: 4
 */
int isPower2(int x) {
    return x <= 0
        ? 0
        : !(x&(x-1));
}

/* please, always post complete and verifiable code, with header files,
 * and the like, so we can test it without having to first modify it.
 */
int main()
{
    for (;;) {
        int a;
        scanf("%d", &a);
        printf("isPower2(a=%d) => %d\n", a, isPower2(a));
    }
}
```

## NOTE

Anyway, I don't have a clear idea of the result you want to get, as you entitle the question as *Problems about check a integer is zero or negative...* and then you show partial code (see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) about *how to detect if some given integer is a power of two* but then, you show then some strange code to check if a number is negative.  It suffices to do:

```
if (x <= 0) do_bla_bla();
```

and this doesn't produce undefined behaviour with 31 bit right shifts.

## NOTE

if you need to use only the operators in the list, just change `<=` by the following:

```
#define SIGNBIT (~(~0>>1))   /* ALL ONES, SHIFTED ONE BIT RIGHT AND COMPLEMENTED */

return 
    x & SIGNBIT      /* sign bit on, negative number */
 || !x               /* OR x == 0 */
    ? 0
    : !(x&(x-1));
```

The final code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
/*
 * isPower2 - returns 1 if x is a power of 2, and 0 otherwise
 *   Examples: isPower2(5) = 0, isPower2(8) = 1, isPower2(0) = 0
 *   Note that no negative number is a power of 2.  (and zero also, there's no logarithm of zero)
 *   Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>
 *   Max ops: 20
 *   Rating: 4
 */
#define SIGNBIT (~(~0>>1))
int isPower2(int x) {
    return x & SIGNBIT || !x ? 0 : !(x&(x-1));
    /* if anybody tells you are using ? and || operators, just write:
     * if (x & SIGNBIT) return 0;
     * if (!x) return 0;
     * return !(x&(x-1));
     */
}

/* please, always post complete and verifiable code, with header files,
 * and the like, so we can test it without having to first modify it.
 */
int main()
{
    for (;;) {
        int a;
        scanf("%d", &a);
        printf("isPower2(a=%d) => %d\n", a, isPower2(a));
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Mr.Colorado, firstly I want to thank you sincerely, for your remarkable patience and time. I am a Chinese student, to be honest, in China almost nobody will spend much time to give a detailed explanation for a question which might not be properly posted. Thank you again for you help, I will try to ask question with suitable and detailed technical explanation next time.

Comment: As you can see, to check whether a positive number is a power of 2, take an ex ample,   1000000,  you minis one it will be 01111111, so x&(x-1) will be 0 if the int is a power of 2.

Comment: What I learned from your answer is how to check <=0  with bit manipulation properly, just using the sign bit, I am new to C, so sorry for my little ignorance.

Comment: My pretend for int b is,  for zero and negative number,  after minus one, the sign bit will be 1, for positive number, their sign  bit will remain 0.  So after you right shift 31bits,  for negative number and zero it will be 0x11111111111(-1),  positve going to be 0x000000000(0),  adding one then you just get the right booelan .  But it seems it doesn't properly work in my code, so that's what I am confusing. But I think it is not so significant, any way :)

Comment: I've tested the code... Have you tested it?  What's exactly the point where it doesn't work?  The sign check is done before doing anything with the number.